# Meaning of 'independency'

Tags: probability, terminology, independence, polya-urn-model

Given a sequence of random variables $X_n$, what does it mean that they are not an "independency"? I have never met such terminology before. Is it just bad English to say that they are not mutually independent? Or is it a precise concept separate from mutual independence of the sequence? I will provide the context too: we are dealing with the indicator functions that mark the draw of a certain color in a Polya urn experiment. Say the black one. So if we call $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ and $B_i,W_i$ the number of black and white balls at time $i$ we have $X_n\sim Bernoulli(B_n/(W_n+B_n))$ conditionally on the filtration.

Comment: That's not a standard term.  I'd look to the source for a definition.

Comment: I forgot the source, but no definition was involved, it was just an old exercise sheet...

Comment: I do believe it is not standard too... maybe it is just wrong. I was just curious if it actually had some specific meaning...

Comment: Well, at a guess I'd say that it was just an odd way to say the variables are dependent.

Comment: What I was wondering is if there was a term to express the fact that they are not mutually independent BUT they are to some extent, meaning that they only influence the probability parameter, not the outcome of each other. I believe some more standard terminology in the field would be like 'the random variables have such Bernoulli distribution, conditionally on the filtration, and are OTHERWISE independent'. I was wondering if it was another way somehow connected to this sort of idea.

Comment: I do not believe there is a single term to describe that.  If there is, it is certainly not universally recognized.  I'd say a thing like that should be spelled out and defined precisely.